# cURL and file_get_contents function are not working (try to get content of page on local site)

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have such code:

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$json_url = "$SiteHost/inc/json.php?action=get_counters";
#$json_url = "http://google.com";

$json = file_get_contents($json_url);

/*
$ch = curl_init($json_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
*/

var_dump($json);

#$counters = json_decode($json);
?>
```

If `$url` content is local link `var_dump` results is `string(0) ""`.
Both cURL and file_get_contents are working if there are link like `http://google.com` (not local link) on `$url`. But if I have in `$url` link to my site (local link) both curl and file_get_contents` are not working. Whyyy?? I tried on localserver (openserver 4.9.0) firstly. After that I thought that may be this problem appears only on local machine and tried it on hosting. Same result. 

Help me please guys! Save my day!

p.s.: `$SiteHost = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`

Comment: What is `$json_url` exactly? What happens in you paste it in your browser and go?

Comment: Sure all working fine. [directly writed url in browser](http://i.gyazo.com/30a50501efb8a78ec3aac68fb208de03.png) If I write same in script `http://test.site/inc/json.php?action=get_counters` (without `$SiteHost`) same result will be printed: `string(0) ""`.